# why serial correlation still yields unbiased and consistent parameters

Tags: statistics

Why is it that when we have serial correlation, we still get unbiased and consistent estimates of true model parameters? (Intuitively)

And (a follow-up question) why do we get the same results for heteroskedastic models?

Comment: That's not true, what are your sources for these claims?

Comment: Wooldridge: Intro to Econometrics; maybe I misunderstood, but from what I've read OLS yields unbiased and consistent estimates both in presence of autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity (only stops being BLUE loses efficiency, and accuracy in inference)